# Can't perform a cleanup in svn

Tags: svn

I try to make a cleanup in **Zend Studio 8**. I get this message:

```
Some of selected resources were not cleaned.

svn: Error processing command 'upgrade-format' in 'C:\Users\Gunnar\Zend\workspaces\DefaultWorkspace7\scripts\release'
svn: Unexpected format number:
   expected: 9
     actual: 10
```

What does this mean?

And how do I solve it?

Comment: try running svn cleanup from the command line?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to the working directory in a terminal, and go into the `.svn` directory there. There's a file called `format`. Cat out that file. It consists of a single number. This is the number of the working directory format.

Format 10 is for Subversion 1.6. I take it that format 9 is for Subversion 1.5. Did you mix up the command line and built in Zend Subversion clients by any chance, or maybe use TortiousSVN? It is possible that Zend is using an older format for the working copy than the other Subversion client, and that Subversion client *upgraded* the working copy for you.

You must be ***very careful*** when using multiple Subversion clients. Subversion does not guarantee that the format of the working directory for one client is compatible with the working directory for another client.

Unfortunately, I can't tell you want needs to be done until I know more about your situation.

- What OS are you on?
- Is Zend a plugin to Eclipse? (The screen shots I saw look that way).
- Do you have a Subversion command line client or TortoiseSVN installed? (Tortoise, by the way installs a Subversion command line client.
- Did you mix up Subversion clients in the same working directory?
- Is the Subversion client a *plugin* for Zend. I've never used Zend, so I can't say. Can you find out what version of the Subversion client plugin in Zend? And, also your other Subversion clients too, if you can.

If you mixed up clients, go to the client you used that *updated* your working directory. Check in all of your changes in there, then checkout a fresh copy in Zend and be careful with mixing Subversion clients.

If you can answer the above questions, I might be able to help you out a bit more. If Zend is an Eclipse plugin, you might be able to upgrade your Eclipse Subversion plugin (either Subclipse or Subversive) to the latest version of the client API. Then upgrade any other client to the same version number.

Comment: Spot on! I have been using two svn-clients without being aware of the risk. In my Windows7 environment I am using a svn-plugin in ZendStudio, version 1.5.6

I ran an update from the command-line in the virtual-box environment that I use.(CentOS 5.7) It has svn 1.6.11
I had no idea it was stupid. I am sincerely grateful that you have pointed out the cause of the problem!

I can in ZendStudio also use svn 1.6.15. I tried switching to this svn-connector but get the same error. Svn version is 1.6.11 on the server where the repository is.

All my format-files contains 9, so no luck there.

Comment: The server version is almost irrelevant. At this time, any client can work on any server. The client is important, and there are differences between the way the Unix and Windows client works that makes using a Unix client on a Windows working directory risky. There is a Windows command line client, and I've used that with Cygwin to get the _Unix tools_, but I wouldn't recommend that either.

Comment: Isn't ZendStudio a Java program? Why not use that on your VirtualBox CentOS? Better yet, put CentOS on your desktop and use VirtualBox to do Windows. I got sick and tired of trying to cross platform work on Windows, and bring my MacBook to work. My Windows box is there, but I can go weeks without touching it.